# Appending to each line of array

Tags: perl

I am just starting new to Perl and I came across an exercise that I really cant work out in the set framework. Basically I have been asked to append a '#' symbol to the start of each line in the array. But that I should only need to add in 1 extra line of code and possibly modify one existing line. Here is the code:

```
$file = '/etc/passwd';          
open(INFO, $file);              
@lines = <INFO>;                
close(INFO);                    
print @lines;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a for loop:

```
$_ = '#' . $_ for @lines;
```

I suggest this because map will make a new array while this will modify an existing one. If you want to use map, copy the array back to the original array.

```
@lines = map { '#' . $_ } @lines; ## possibly slower since it creates a new array then copies it
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) function:

```
print map { '#' . $_ } @lines;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying [this exercise](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/filehandling.html#exercise), which comes from [this tutorial](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/). Please don't do that. Why would you want to learn a programming language from a tutorial that starts by saying:

> Please note: This tutorial was written in the early 1990's for version
>   4 of Perl. Although it is now significantly out of date, it was a
>   popular source of information for many people over many years. It has
>   therefore been left on-line as part of the historical archive of the
>   Internet.

You'd be far better off using the (modern) resources listed at [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org/).

The question is flawed anyway. You don't need to add a line of code, you just need to modify an existing one.

```
print map { "# $_" } @lines;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
close INFO;
grep{ $_ = "#$_"; undef } @lines;
```

Without the **undef** the grep would assemble a matching array for return, which is discarded. As **undef** grep will now discard everything. Why this works you need to dig out on your own.

Extra credit: benchmark the different solutions to find the fastest. See the Benchmark module

Answer (score 0):

It's perl, so there are probably dozens of way to do it, here is one:

```
print "#" . join('#', @lines);
```

Answer (score -1):

By adding the first two lines you can achieve that.

```
$file = "inputfile";
`sed 's/^/#/g' /etc/passwd > inputfile`;
open(INFO, $file);
@lines = <INFO>;
close(INFO);
print @lines;
```

Comment: -1 for: a) using an extra file. b) using sed from perl for perl-stuff c) using back ticks when system should be used (your ignoring the output, right). d) not checking return codes.

Comment: @pavel a) I don't understand why should you vote down for using extra file? It would work perfectly. b) Why should not we use sed from perl? d) The OP expects some logic to handle his situation, he doesn't expect how to handle each statement.

Do not exploit down votes when not necessary.

Comment: @cppcoder I don't see this answer as particularly helpful. Why shell out to another command to do what is a one-liner in perl (shoot, you could have used that same sed regex unchanged)? The OP goal was to do this in perl.

Comment: Is there anything bad to show alternate ways? OP can decide whichever answer that suits his need.

Comment: @cppcoder: The OP wants to learn perl, so in my opinion he's better helped with (good) perl examples then non-perl alternatives. Of course there are many other ways (sed, bash, java, C), but it's a perl question, nothing else...